# How to get columns from different table B based on condition of column on table A?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

suppose i have two tables table A and table B

Table A

```
id name remarks
 4  X    XXX
 6  Y    YYY
 7  Z    ZZZ
```

Table B

```
id Aid    remarks        edit_flag
 1   4     NULL            0
 2   6     YY changes      1
 3   7     Z cahnged       1
```

so, i would like to retrieve data like below:

if edit_flag is 1 (that is edited), get remarks column from table B else(edit_flag is 0) get remarks column from table A since it isnt edited

i am looking at something like this

```
if(edit_flag == 0) 
    then get remarks from table A 
else get remarks from table B
```

so my result table should be looking like

```
Row_Counter remarks 
1 XXX 
2 YY changes 
3 Z changed
```

Comment: Take a look to JOIN clause:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: i know joins...but i dont know how to construct,

i am looking at something like this

if(edit_flag == 0)
then get remarks from table A
else
get remarks from table B

so my result table should be looking like 
Row_Counter    remarks      
 1                     XXX            
 2        YY changes
 3        Z cahnged 

i can do it from the programming end but i am looking for some sql learning too...

will it work with ifwhen/then clause or dynamic sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CASE`:

```
SELECT aID = a.id, name,
       remarks = CASE b.edit_flag 
                    WHEN 0 THEN a.remarks
                    WHEN 1 THEN b.remarks
                 END
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.Aid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join 2 tables and make a conditional query. Such as:

NOTE: I'm assuming that you're using a database supporting "iif". Otherwise you should use "case" as in the other answers.

```
Select a.id as id_id, iif(b.edit_flag = 0, a.remarks, b.remarks) as remark
  from tableA as a inner join tableB as b on a.id=b.Aid
```

Comment: `IIF` introduced in `SQL SERVER 2012`

Answer (score 0):

Use Case Statement

```
    declare @tblA as table
(
    id int,
    name varchar(50),
    remarks varchar(50)
)


insert into @tblA values(4,'x','xxx');
insert into @tblA values(6,'y','yyy');
insert into @tblA values(7,'z','zzz');

declare @tblB as table
(
    id int,
    Aid int,    
    remarks varchar(50),
    edit_flag int
)


insert into @tblB values(1,4,NULL,0);
insert into @tblB values(2,6,'yy changes',1);
insert into @tblB values(3,7,'z changes',1);

SELECT 
    B.id,
    B.Aid,
    B.edit_flag,    
    CASE WHEN edit_flag=1 THEN B.remarks ELSE a.remarks END as remarks
FROM @tblB B
LEFT JOIN @tblA A ON B.Aid=A.id
```

Comment: Already someone wrote similar answer. It is good that you have added the test script still this is duplicate answer. Also OP didnot mention that he/she wants all the records from @tblB

Comment: That's why some one has answered prior me